# Getting all composite children keys

Tags: java, database, cassandra, hector

So let's say that I have the following structure in cassandra:

```
<L1> (key:L2, value:value0);
<L1:0> (key:L3, value:value0);
<L1:0> (key:L3, value:value0);
<L1:0> (key:L3, value:value0);
```

Now I want to get all children of "L1". So the expected result is supposed to be (L2 and 0), but result that I get so far is (L2, 0, 0, 0). How can I remove these multiple 0 from query.

In hector I'm making follow query:

```
composite start, end;
start.addComponent(0, "L1", EQUAL);
end.addComponent(0, "L1", GREATER_THAN_EQUAL);
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your notation.  What do you mean by 'L1' and 'L1:0'? Are they supposed to be cassandra column family keys?

Comment: Yes, exactly. "L1" and etc are column family composite keys

Comment: Could you paste the create column family statement(s) you used to create the column family?

Comment: I'm creating column family using hector so I just use .setComparatorTypeAlias("UTF8TYPE", "UTF8TYPE", "UTF8TYPE");